# Error while executing pub get even after having ssh key

Tags: flutter, git, github, ssh, flutter-dependencies

```
Git error. Command: `git clone --mirror git@github.com:open-runtime/aot_monorepo.git /Users/tarun/.pub-cache/git/cache/aot_monorepo-7a0b3d0f0477d2766d0540e8a0101f937bb7f0bf`
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/tarun/.pub-cache/git/cache/aot_monorepo-7a0b3d0f0477d2766d0540e8a0101f937bb7f0bf'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
exit code: 128
```

I tried to execute `pub get` for the first time after cloning in IntelliJ IDE . I faced the same error previously for a different repository belonging to the same organisation, then I figured out that I didn't really verify the ssh keys, which I did and worked fine. Now I am getting the exact same error for different repo belonging to the same org. The repo's are hosted on GitHub. OS is Mac , also did `ssh -T git@github.com` and it said I was authenticated.

Answer (score 2):

Since I get a 404 not found when accessing https://github.com/open-runtime/aot_monorepo, I suppose the repository is private.

Your SSH key might be valid, and you might be correctly authenticated to GitHub, but... you need to make sure you were [invited to this repository](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository).